# RecyclerView is not visible in bottomsheet fragment

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I have one bottom sheet fragment which contains one header, one subheader and one recycler view to show some sort of offer.
Below is the layout.

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_back_arrow" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:text="header"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/offer_sub_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=" sub title offer"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/space"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/offer_sub_title" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here my recycler view is not visible.
I have set the `android:layout_height` as 0dp. If I change it to `wrap_content`, recycler view is visible but it is overlapping with subheader.